# Extract only values from JSON key:value pair using python

Tags: python, json

I've searched around and have not seen anything that quite covers what I need to do, so if I missed the answer in my search please refer me to the proper link, thanks in advance. Simply, all I want to do is take two values form a JSON object list that I'm calling in and remove two values from each object in the list, not the entire key:value.

My code at the moment looks like so:

```
import json, urllib2, pprint

url = ('url_to_be_read')
urlFile = urlib2.urlopen(url)
jsonList = json.load(urlFile)

pprint (jsonList['domain']
```

I had tried this way as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580120/3483414 but both ways I get: "Keyerror: 'domain' "

A example of my JSON object list(after calling it and pprinting it to test) is as follows:

```
 # Edited as requested
 {u'data': [{u'categories': [],
             u'ip': u'123.456.78.9',
             u'domain': u'com.somedomain',
             u'handler': 7},
            {u'categories': [],
             u'ip': u'9.876.543.21',
             u'domain': u'com.differendomain',
             u'handler': 7}],
  u'elapsedTime': 130,
  u'successful': True}
```

The simple gist is that I just want the values from IP and domain from each object in the list. I haven't bothered to try and retrieve the second part (IP) until I get the first part figured out. Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: You need to show us *more* of the JSON loaded. You apparently have a top-level dictionary, and at least one of the values contains a list with *more* dictionaries. The top-level dict has no `domain` key, it's those nested dictionaries that do.

Comment: Instead of using urllib, try python requests. http://docs.python-requests.org/
It really rocks ;)

Comment: I had used requests the first time around, I was just trying different things out, thanks. I've also updated the list as requested.

Comment: Is this the actual json? I see a missing `}`.

Comment: Sorry, i fixed it, the list is rather long so I just spliced it.

Comment: Now that we have a proper object, you can see that the top level has a `data` key, and that key references a list of other dictionaries. `jsonList['data'][0]['domain']` exists, therefor. You haven't yet told us *what you want to do* with this data. What is the expected output?

Comment: I think what you need `for i in jsonList['data']: if i['domain'] == 'something': do something`, but beyond this I don't know what you want because this sentence is not parsing for me: _"take two values form a JSON object list that I'm calling in and remove two values from each object in the list, not the entire key:value"_

Comment: Ah, thanks for that clarification, newb to both json and python here. I am looking to get just the corresponding ip and domains out so that I can sort them at a later point in time to see how many times each appears, and take the highest ones used so that it can be put into a .csv down the road.

Comment: When you say corresponding, do you just mean "all the ips and domains"?

Comment: Yes, the values of just the ip and domain keys.

Comment: @v3rbal: it depends heavily on what you are going to do with the data as to what makes a useful structure for you to extract these values into. A list of `(domain, ip)` tuples? A dictionary, mapping `ip` to `domain`? Two separate lists, one of `domain` values, the other of `ip` values?

Comment: All thats going to happen for the moment is they are going to be written to a file, sorting and uniqueness is not the issue at the moment, just how to iterate over it and pull out the values of those two keys. Nothing more, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1):

So after hacking around and a little more google, the answer I came up with was:

```
import requests, json

r = r.requests.get('path_to_url.tld')
j = r.text
j = json.loads(j)
json_string = json.dumps(j,sort_keys=True, indents=2)
parent = j['data']
for item in parent:
    print item["domain"]
        print item["ip"]
```

Which will give me what I want in my file to use later of:

```
someDomain.com
123.4.5.6
otherDomain.net
12.34.56.78
```

Thanks for everyones attempt at helping.